# How to revert an redux action call with some message inside that action call in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, redux-thunk

First of all, I am new to redux. I am trying to create a CRUD react application with `redux` and `jsonPlaceholderAPI`. I am using redux-thunk as redux middleware. In my `fetchResources` action, I am calling the `GET` api and sending the response to reducer to update the store. But my problem is, How can I send some error message back when the API call fails due to any system error. For a better understanding [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-http-6hl8r?file=/src/components/post/PostList.js) is the link to my crud project up & ready in `codesandbox`. In case I did not make myself clear, I want to know the procedure when the action call fails and how to handle it with some message to user. I have added the core code snippets of my projects below.

**Action**

```
import jsonPlaceholder from '../apis/jsonPlaceholder';
import _ from 'lodash';

export const fetchPosts = () => async(dispatch)=>{
    let {data} = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts');
    data = _.drop(data, 95);
    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload:data});
};

export const createPost = ({title, body}) => async dispatch=>{
    let {data}  = await jsonPlaceholder.post('/posts',{title, body, userId:_.random(1,10)});
    dispatch({type:'CREATE_POST', payload:data});
};

export const updatePost = (post) => async dispatch=>{
    let {data}  = await jsonPlaceholder.put(`/posts/${post.id}`,post);
    dispatch({type:'UPDATE_POST', payload:data});
};

export const deletePost = (postId) => async dispatch=>{
    await jsonPlaceholder.delete(`/posts/${postId}`);
    dispatch({type:'DELETE_POST', payload:postId});
};
```

**Reducer**

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case "FETCH_POSTS":
    return action.payload;
  case "CREATE_POST":
    return [...state, action.payload];
  case "UPDATE_POST":
    return state.map((post) =>
      post.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : post
    );
  case "DELETE_POST":
    return state.filter((post) => post.id !== action.payload);
  default:
    return state;
}
};

/***Index Reducer***/
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import postReducers from '../reducers/postReducers';

export default combineReducers({
    posts: postReducers
});
```

**Main Component**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Post from "./Post";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts } from "../../actions";

const PostList = ({ posts, fetchPosts }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
  const list = posts.map((post) => <Post key={post.id} post={post} />);
  return <>{list}</>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(PostList);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If your API call returns and error, you can verify if your response contain an error, or some error status and dispatch an Error Action:

   export const updatePost = (post) => async dispatch=>{

   ```
       const response  = await jsonPlaceholder.put(`/posts/${post.id}`,post);
       if(response.status !== 200 || response.error (*for example)) {
        dispatch({type:'ERROR', payload:response.error});


   } else {
            dispatch({type:'UPDATE_POST', payload:response.data});

     }
        };
   ```

Also you can create some wrapper for it.

2. Axios provides you with interceptors
   https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

you can use it and dispath an Error Action if there is some response error